# Magento 2 Custom MassAction redirects to dashboard with "Invalid Security Token" but works?

Tags: module, redirect, massaction

I created a custom mass action, and it shows up and seems to function fine except rather than redirecting back to the order page, it goes to the admin dashboard and says the typical "Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page."

I've removed most of the code for the actual mass action part of it and narrowed it down to something I must be doing wrong with the redirect.

I've done the usual setup:di:compile, setup:upgrade, cache:flush to attempt to fix it but I am stuck with this for now.

Here's my MassAction.php

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Export;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 
class Pdf extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
{
    protected $fileFactory;
    protected $csvProcessor;
    protected $directoryList;
    protected $timezone;
    protected $request;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $collectionFactory;
    protected $_orderHelper;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){  
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->timezone = $timezone;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    
    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $orderIds = $collection->getAllIds();
        
        file_put_contents("/report.txt","Works"); // this is fired and written to disk
        
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath($this->getComponentRefererUrl()); // rather than returning to the order panel, it does to the admin dashboard?

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the ADMIN_RESOURCE was not set
2. the redirect url needed to be somewhat
   different to the core as your massaction url is in another module
   that sale/order

The code below works better

```
<?php
             
            namespace Egghead\LabelMaker\Controller\Adminhtml\Export;
            
            use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
            use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
            use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
            use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
            use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
            use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
            
            class Labels extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
                implements \Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface
            {
                /**
                 * Authorization level of a basic admin session
                 */
                const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Egghead_LabelMaker::labelmaker';
            
                protected $fileFactory;
                protected $csvProcessor;
                protected $directoryList;
                protected $timezone;
                protected $request;
                protected $scopeConfig;
                protected $collectionFactory;
                protected $_orderHelper;
            
                public function __construct(
                    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
                    \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
                    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
                    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
                    \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $csvProcessor,
                    \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
                    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
                    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
                ){  
                    parent::__construct($context, $filter);
                    $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
                    $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
                    $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
                    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
                    $this->timezone = $timezone;
                    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
                }
                
                protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
                {
                    $orderIds = $collection->getAllIds();
                    
                    file_put_contents("/report.txt","Works"); // this is fired and written to disk
            
                    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                    $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order');
                    return $resultRedirect;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I believe that may have worked, it now says `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/AbstractMassAction.php:61` which I traced to being something about it not liking the collection

Comment: Hmm ok so that still didn't solve the issue, regardless is it better practice to use */*/ vs the line I used previously?

Comment: No worries, thanks for the responses, what other files would help? This is the entirety of the Pdf.php file, is there something else that could help?

Comment: Ideally the module that does make up the screen but not mandatory.. if I can have your issue on my local of course it speed the solution and make it more reliable

Comment: No worries, thanks for all your help

Comment: it is now downloaded

Comment: Thanks, some combo of the code above seems to have solved it

Comment: Great it worked out, enjoyed it, thanks